# Jupyter Notebook: Access Google Cloud API

Tags: python, docker, jupyter-notebook

I am running my Jupyter notebooks locally via Docker ([jupyter/scipy-notebook](https://github.com/jupyter/docker-stacks/tree/master/scipy-notebook))

So far I always accessed APIs by saving the credentials in the .env file where the Dockerfile lives. However, now I start working with Google Cloud and the private keys are "handed over" to me in a [private key JSON file](https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/docs/quickstart-client-libraries?authuser=1). I now wonder how that works together with the .env I am currently using. Can I just insert the path to the file in my .env file? Probably not... but I currently have no better idea.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I remember, you will have to create an environment variable called `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` and the value is the path to that JSON file key you've got.

The `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` is the default name Google libraries will look for in determining the path to the key. This is done when you create an instance of the specific client library.

Here's a link. Section **Setting the environment variable** talks about it.
https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started